# How do I write a simple key listener in Java that will save the input to a .txt file?

Tags: java, keypress, keylogger, keyrelease

I'm fairly inexperienced with Java and I was curious if there was a simple/easy way to write a .java that would log keyboard input from all locations in the OS and save them to a .txt (or similar) file (or even just a java panel). I've seen mention of methods like `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, and `KeyTyped` but I don't know how to properly implement those. If someone could explain that would be great.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is to use Java to create a key-logger, and you will find that this is something that cannot be done with core Java. Java was created to be as operating system agnostic as possible, and what you are trying to do requires a closer association with the operating system than can be achieved with core Java.

Solutions can be achieved but they require meshing Java with native code using JNI, JNA or similar libraries or by meshing Java with os-specific utilities, but these of necessitate your creating non-portable solutions.

Comment: I have heard that but on the oracle docs site they have a key-logger that does more or less what I want, I just don't understand all of the concepts contained in it so I can't make the changes I would need to use it.

Comment: Also, by non-portable, do you mean that it could only be used on one type of OS or only on one hard drive?

Comment: @mills.i: by non-portable, I mean that it will work on only one OS. If you can get the source code for the program you mention, then by all means study it. But I am surprised that a web site can log all keyboard input on a client system.

Comment: I was not intending to have a website based program, it would be on a hard drive.

Comment: to use the one on oracle docs you have to download the .java and compile it

Comment: @mills.i: but you stated that such a program existed on a web site, and so I don't know how they achieved that. What program do you mean?

Comment: Check it out for yourself, here's the link.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/index.html#KeyEventDemo

It is the one titled "MultiListener" four from the bottom.

Comment: @mills.i: have you run that program? It doesn't listen to OS key strokes at all.

Comment: No, I hadn't. The link to it cited it as one that did. Back to your idea, how difficult is it to mesh java with native code?

Comment: @mills.i: You will want to be above a beginner level with both Java and C (since the Windows API reference has mostly C style information). What is your purpose for this anyway? Most key loggers are used for, shall we say, less than reputable reasons.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just curious about the concept. I wasn't planning to make it super secret or anything. thanks for the time, looks like its above my head for now. I've got some Visual C# but I really am just starting java.